# MySQL : Update multiple values based on informatin from select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have on table were dates are mixed up, the startDate and endDate columns need to be switched. I am use to using SQL Server and this could be accomplished using a cursor in SQL Server, but in MySQL you can only use a cursor inside a SP which i do not want

The following statement returns all the records that need to be updated

```
select * from calendarTable where endDate < startDate;
```

I have tried the following code but this first sets the startDate to the value of the endDate then the endDate to the new value of the startDate so this ends as both dates being the same and not switched

```
update calendarTable
set startDate  = endDate,
    endDate = startDate
where startDate > endDate;
```

Is there a way of doing this in MySQL similar to a cursor in SQL Server or how would you do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL for the most part evaluates assignments in left-to-right order. If you want to swap the values in two fields, you have to use a temp variable to hold one of the values while moving things around:

```
UPDATE @temp := startDate, startDate = endDate, endDate = @temp
```

Assignments within a statement take immediate effect, so if you "reuse" a changed field later on in the query, you get the updated value, not the original one:

```
mysql> select * from foo;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
|    1 |
|   10 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update foo set x=x+1, x=x+50;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from foo;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
|   52 |
|   61 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

if MySQL used the "original" values for the right-hand side, then the final table would've been `51` and `60`, because the values created by the `+1` component would've been trashed by the later `+10`.

Instead, you get a "live" value at each usage in the query, so a field's value depends entirely on what you're doing with it inside the query, and where you're using it in the query.

Comment: but how would you do this for mutliple updates... for example, if my select statement `select * from calendarTable where endDate < startDate;` returned 2000 records, i need something to loop over the 2000 records and update them all

Comment: exactly as you would for a single row. mysql doesn't work "across" rows. a row is a little universe by itself, and updates only work on single rows at a time (unless you start mixing in self-joins and other more advanced things). So even if your table has 5000 records, you'd do 5000 individual "sub-updates" with your single `update ...` query.

Comment: then how do you set the temp values in the update statement so you can just switch the two fields and not update the two fields with a given value?

Comment: exactly like I put in my sample above. `select @temp := ....`. `@temp` gets assigned the start date value of every row, you swap start/end dates, then end date gets whatever's in @temp. and whoops, just realized I'd put `select` in there. should've been an `update @temp := ....`

Comment: sorry, i tried what you were saying but did not work. do not know if you were not understanding what i was looking for or i wasnt understanding what you were saying but i sorted it out with an inner join on the update... thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 0):

i managed to do this by using an joining on a select as below

```
UPDATE calendarTable as cal, 
(
    select id,startDate,endDate from calendarTable where endDate < startDate
) as temp
SET cal.startDate = temp.endDate, cal.endDate = temp.startDate  WHERE cal.ID = temp.ID;
```